# Shopify Triggers

Tags: shopify, admin

I am new to shopify api.

I am creating an application which should receive post requests when certain events happen in Shopify.

For example events could be "When an order gets fullfilled" or "product payment status is upi" or "product tag include the following" etc.Basically I wanted to create trigger.

I have heard of webhooks as well as workflows

What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Shopify Webhook is the best option to stay in sync with Shopify or execute code after a specific event occurs in a shop on shopify.